# How to mapp bean URL to controller Mappings in spring

Tags: spring, url, url-parameters, url-mapping

I have below requirement.
The current URLs (ends with .htm)are mapped directly to controller class, but now the URL request will be changing, where user will login from some other application and that application triggers actual URL by prefixing user name as an URL attribute, those user ID should be tracked from my application and other functionalities should be same as before.

Current URL is like this: "server:port/xyz/abc.htm"
Future URL will be like this : "server:port/xyz/abc.htm?user=lax"

Current bean mapping for first URL:

```
<bean name="/abc.htm" class="abcControllerClass">
    <property name="commandName">
        <value>DataCommand</value>
    </property>
    <property name="commandClass">
        <value>dataClass</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I map for second URL?

Comment: The name of a bean is not a url mapping.

Comment: It is used currently like this, can you let me know if there is any other way we can handle mapping?